# Does a geminal or vicinal diiodide form upon addition of excess HI to but-2-yne?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Reaction: $\ce{CH3-C#C-CH3 + HI (excess) -> ?}$

Product : I thought of different carbons by the reasoning from [this post earlier I posted](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149820/106350). But it is given that both iodine atoms exist on the same carbon.

Is this an exception or is the answer given incorrect?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138882/mechanism-for-the-addition-of-hydrogen-iodide-to-3-3-dimethylbut-1-yne

Does this help?

Comment: I think the reason might be since this reaction follows a termolecular mechanism whereas the reaction you had posted earlier involved us to check the stability of the carbocation being formed and the final product being formed.